# SQL Update returning zero rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE starfsfolk
SET starfsfolk.stada=2
WHERE starfsfolk.deild LIKE '%Hugbúnaðardeild%';

UPDATE starfsfolk
SET starfsfolk.stada=3
WHERE starfsfolk.deild LIKE '%Markaðsdeild%'
```

is prescisely the code i'm using.

i've tried various different versions of it(like = "Markaðsdeild" or LIKE "Markaðsdeild")

most of which work if i'm using select, but i needed to use update and its not working for some reason.

This WHERE command works on select but
it returns zero rows if i'm using the update command. What am i doing wrong?

Edit:
Just to clarify, stada is set to 1 in all cases before and after the update command. it hasn't changed from 1 to 2 and 3 like i wanted it to.

Edit2: heres [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYZHo.png) of the database, i could also give you the create commands.

Edit3: Stada is bit, not int, i found out, not sure what that changes tho.

Solution: Solved myself, since bit is just 1 and 0, the error was in the creation of the table so i remade it with stada as int and now the code is working.

Comment: If row that you want to update have the same value, then mysql will return UPDATED 0.
Also mysql workbench dont allow to update using WHERE LIKE statments by default.

Comment: Give some sample data. So the we can check your query.

Comment: UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed.

Comment: Have you tried to substitute the `LIKE` for a... `WHERE starfsfolk.deild = 'Markaðsdeild'`?
I generally use commands of this type and it works.

Comment: WHERE starfsfolk.deild = 'Hugbúnaðardeild';# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of stada is not changed by the query then zero rows will be returned because nothing was updated.

Answer (score 0):

The character sets of the server and of the client are different.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html